# Check if git branch exists in while loop

Tags: git, bash

Hi there i am trying to prompt the user for a branch to push to. Im am trying to handle if the user enter the wrong name. I dont have much experience with bash but I really enjoying it.

```
while [ "$(git branch --list ${branch_name})" ]
do
    read -r -p "${BLUE}What branch do you want to push to: ${RESET}" branch_name 
done
```

I have tried a few things like using different type of quotes, just quotes, ect .. with no joy.

What would be the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing, first, only the Git side of things, what you're doing may be inadvisable in the first place.

#### Is this wise?

Your question asks: *What branch do you want to **push to**?* (emphasis mine), but `git push` takes a *refspec*, which represents *two potentially different* branch names: a *local* name, in your own repository, which you can match against existing branches in the local repository, and a *foreign* name, in some *other* Git repository.  The foreign branch name does not even need to exist in the first place.  If it *does* exist, it does not have to match the local branch name.

For instance, I can:

```
git push origin HEAD:newbranch
```

to push my current commit to a newly-created branch on `origin`.

#### Shell code to test whether a name is a valid branch name

All that said, if you wish to check whether a shell variable holds a valid *branch name* (as opposed to some other string that can be resolved to a commit ID, such as `HEAD` or `ac0ffee` or `v2.1.3`), the way to find out is, generally, to use `git rev-parse` to *fully qualify* the name.  There are several subtle traps here though:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --verify --quiet master
refs/heads/master
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --verify --quiet asdf
$ echo $?
1
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --verify --quiet v2.1.1
refs/tags/v2.1.1
```

Hence we might try:

```
is_branch() {
    local name="$1" fullname

    if fullname=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name \
            --verify --quiet "$name"); then
        case "$fullname" in
        refs/heads/*) return 0;; # valid branch name
        esac
    fi
    return 1 # not a valid branch name
}
```

However:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --verify --quiet HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

it turns out that this follows symbolic names (such as `HEAD` when it is not "detached") and expands them to their corresponding target.  It does this for *any* symbolic name, although `HEAD` is the only normal local symbolic name, so if you wish to disallow `HEAD`, you have two obvious options:

- see if the name is the literal string `HEAD` (catches one common case), or
- use `git symbolic-ref` to see if the name is a symbolic reference (catches all cases).

Another, less obvious option is to use `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev`, which produces the short form of the *target* name of a symbolic reference:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master
master
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
master
```

We could then compare the output against the input: if they are the same, the name is not a symbolic reference.  The flaw here is that if the name is a *tag* name, its abbreviated reference name is still itself:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref v2.1.1
v2.1.1
```

so we still need a full-name check anyway.  So I would recommend `git symbolic-ref` here, e.g.:

```
is_branch() {
    local name="$1" fullname

    if fullname=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name \
            --verify --quiet "$name"); then
        case "$fullname" in
        refs/heads/*) # valid branch name; check if symbolic
            git symbolic-ref --quiet "$name" >/dev/null && return 0
            ;;
        esac
    fi
    return 1 # not a valid branch name
}
```

But, do this *only* if you have reason to *explicitly reject* indirect names like `HEAD`.  (Note that `git push origin HEAD:HEAD` is generally a bad idea, but `git push origin HEAD` is not so bad, since your Git will *locally* resolve the indirection and, in effect, `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` if `HEAD` is a symbolic name for `master`.  If `HEAD` is *detached* it won't resolve to any branch name in the first place, so that particular case is not a problem here.)

#### Putting it together

Now that we have an `is_branch`, we can use that:

```
while ! is_branch "$branch_name"; do
    ...
done
```

Note that it may be a good idea to list the branch name options (i.e., run `git branch --list`) inside the loop, which is something you effectively got for free before.

Comment: Legend, thanks for your great response i am sure lots of people will benefit from this post.

Comment: It doesn't work if the branch is only listed in `git ls-remote`

Comment: @CodyChan: if `git ls-remote` lists the branch name, *you* don't have the branch name, *they* (the remote) have the branch name. Their branch name is not your branch name! If you want to *get* that branch name, you must choose a commit to which you'd like to have that branch name point (in your repository), make sure that this commit *exists in* your repository, then *create* that branch name (in your repository). That's a job for `git fetch` plus one more Git command.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you are asking something like

> As long as [*list of branches*], ask user for a branch name.

You have to write

> As long as [*user input*] not in [*list of branches*], ask user for a branch name.

Try

```
branch_name=
while ! grep -qwF "$branch_name" <(git branch --list)
do
    read -r -p "${BLUE}What branch do you want to push to: ${RESET}" branch_name 
done
```

The `grep` part searches for the entered branch name inside the list of branches and returns `0` (= true = success) if the branch name was found. Since we want to ask for branch names as long as the branch does *not* exist, we negate the exit code using `!`. Alternatively you could write `until grep` instead of `while ! grep`.